# Web sql database earased when users update app from App store

Tags: cordova, web-sql

I have a cordova application which uses web sql databse. Before releasing this version I have updated a table to include to new columns. When user update the APP previous data is erased. If user install a new copy it works and on updating user is unable to find any previous data.

I can't even alter the table because I don't know if user already has table or not. Currently I am using 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS' to create a table.

var myDB = openDatabase('test', 1.0, 'Native APP', 5*1024*1024);

I have tried changing the version of the database from 1.0 to 2.0 but to no avail. Need some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised to see no answers to this question.So I found something Here is How you do it,

```
var db = openDatabase("example_db", "", "Example Database", 100000);

if(db.version == ""){
  db.changeVersion("", "1", function(t){
    t.executeSql("create table foo...");
  }, null /* error callback */, function(){
    // success callback
    db.changeVersion("1", "2", function(t){
      t.executeSql("alter table foo...");
    });    
  });
}

if(db.version == "1"){
  db.changeVersion("1", "2", function(t){
    t.executeSql("alter table foo...");
  });
}
```

This worked for me!

Comment: For Reference 
1.) reference http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/03/html5-web-sql-database-intro-to-versioning-and-migrations/

2.)https://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/08/14/Updating-PhoneGap-Databases

Answer (score 0):

From documentation: [W3.org Web SQL Database](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#dom-database-changeversion).
Since changeVersion is an asynchronous method and

> these methods must immediately return and then asynchronously run the
>   transaction steps with the transaction callback being the first
>   argument

, the order in which the checks are made must be carefully evaluated.

```js
/* the version is used only if the callbackfunction is not passed. In this case we pass it and therefore we have to create it with changeversion */
var db = openDatabase('documents', '1.0', 'Offline document storage', 5*1024*1024, 
  function (db) {//Enter only the creation of the database, the first time
    db.changeVersion('', '1.0', function (t) {
      t.executeSql('CREATE TABLE docids (id, name)');
    }, error);
  }
);
/*To make changes to the database, it will be necessary to slowly add the functions thus written*/

if(db.version == "1.0") {
  db.changeVersion("1.0", "1.2", 
 function(trans) {
  //All functions from 1.0 to 1.2
  trans.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO1 (id unique, data, foo)');
        trans.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO2 (id unique, data, foo)');
        trans.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO3 (id unique, data, foo)');
  });
}
else if(db.version == "1.1") {
    db.changeVersion("1.1", "1.2", 
 function(trans) {
  //Only functions from 1.1 to 1.2
        trans.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO2 (id unique, data, foo)');
        trans.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO3 (id unique, data, foo)');
  });
}
```